# error in D3.js code regarding particular place

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization, pie-chart

i am making a college project on D3.js. i copied the code of pie chart from Scott Murray's book on D3.js. It works. But now i am facing a problem.

1)i want to show the pie chart in a particular place in html page ,but i am unable to do it.
 like

2)when i resubmit the data its created another pie chart very next to old one.But i want to first delete old one and then create new one at same place.
 please help me.

the fiddle is-http://jsbin.com/acatof/3/edit

D3: Pie layout

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        text {
            font-family: sans-serif;
            font-size: 12px;
            fill: white;
        }

    </style>
    <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        //Width and height
        var w = 300;
        var h = 300;

        var dataset = [ 5, 10, 20, 45, 6, 25 ];

        var outerRadius = w / 2;
        var innerRadius = 0;
        var arc = d3.svg.arc()
                        .innerRadius(innerRadius)
                        .outerRadius(outerRadius);

        var pie = d3.layout.pie();

        //Easy colors accessible via a 10-step ordinal scale
        var color = d3.scale.category10();

        //Create SVG element
        var svg = d3.select("body")
                    .append("svg")
                    .attr("width", w)
                    .attr("height", h);

        //Set up groups
        var arcs = svg.selectAll("g.arc")
                      .data(pie(dataset))
                      .enter()
                      .append("g")
                      .attr("class", "arc")
                      .attr("transform", "translate(" + outerRadius + "," + outerRadius + ")");

        //Draw arc paths
        arcs.append("path")
            .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
                return color(i);
            })
            .attr("d", arc);

        //Labels
        arcs.append("text")
            .attr("transform", function(d) {
                return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";
            })
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .text(function(d) {
                return d.value;
            });

    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To put it in an element, for example, a `<div>` instead on the `<body>`, you just need to replace the selection on which the `svg` will be appended, to the selector of the element where you want to put the graph.

So instead of

```
var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", w)
            .attr("height", h);
```

You can do:

```
var svg = d3.select("#container")
                .append("svg")
                .attr("width", w)
                .attr("height", h);
```

Provided that there is a `<div id = "container"></div>` somewhere on your page.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: thanks johnroe for reply.
I tried this and its works. But there is a another problem occurring. that because this program work in javascript so when i resubmit the data then it cross the div boundry and make new pie chart very near to old one.
 But i want that if i resubmit the data then it should override the old one and create the new one with fresh data.